# I can't change the settings on the desktop version of Don't Starve

Tags: dont-starve

I've been playing don't starve for a while, and with the last update they added a bloom effect which is a huge decrease in my performance, when near fires my computer drops to 30 FPS or less.

There is an option to toggle it, but turning it off then clicking "Apply" makes my monitor go dark, then when it gets back to normal my desktop icons are scattered as if the resolution was made lower, then higher again. I should also point out that dont starve starts at a huge resolution which goes off my screen, trying to change it in the options doesn't work but resizing the window does.

I tried changing the options in the .ini file but there's no bloom option there, and changing the resolution values has no effect whatsoever.

What can I do to disable the bloom effect and the bad window resolution on start-up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A friend of mine had the same exact problem.  Set the game to full screen (at a good resolution setting) and change the settings.
It seems that when you click "Apply" the game cycles modes, which crashes on some systems.

Comment: Thanks a ton, I was losing hope of getting this answered, i'll try it today.

Comment: I might add, the game doesn't always scale cursor controls correctly.  (Similar to changing resolution in valve games).

Answer (score 0):

Go to `\Documents\Klei\DoNotStarve` and delete the file called settings.

Comment: Thanks! That worked for me, where the accepted answer didn't.